# CI cannot build .NET project, fails with: "Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system..."

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core, debian

I am working on having Jenkins build our legacy .NET 2.1 applications as part of streamlining our kubernetes deployments

Therefore I have created a custom Jenkins agent based on the jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest-jdk11 docker image (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave) which in turn is Debian 9 based, extended with the official .NET Core (unpacked the ZIP from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1 , Debian updates does not work well with our firewall), and for trivial projects this has worked well.

Now I try with a real legacy application which builds nicely when running the commands from the command line, but when Jenkins try to run `dotnet restore -v n` the build immediately fails with:

```
+ dotnet restore -v n
11:11:29  FailFast:
11:11:29  Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
11:11:29  
11:11:29     at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
11:11:29     at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
11:11:29     at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
11:11:29     at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
11:11:29     at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
11:11:29     at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
11:11:29     at System.StringComparer..cctor()
11:11:29     at System.AppDomain.InitializeCompatibilityFlags()
11:11:29     at System.AppDomain.Setup(System.Object)
11:11:29  Aborted (core dumped)
```

Not being very experienced with .NET, I have probably missed a step somewhere when setting up the environment.  The application needs to run in the "da-DK" locale.

I understand that some part is missing.  How should this fixed?  I am interested in both project-specific quick solutions and long-term agent-specific solutions.

Comment: What distribution are you using? Have you checked [How to use .NET Core on RHEL 6 / CentOS 6](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/build-and-install-rhel6-prerequisites.md#making-the-libraries-available-for-a-net-core-application)? The section [Making the libraries available for a .NET Core application](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/build-and-install-rhel6-prerequisites.md#making-the-libraries-available-for-a-net-core-application) shows you need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable too

Answer (score 0):

After locating https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script on the download page, and seeing the "needed dependencies" link combined with the output from the install script, I found that the underlying reason was missing library dependencies, and the fix was to install them in the Dockerfile.

```
# Needed dependencies...
RUN apt install -y libunwind8 libicu57
```

Comment: libunwind8 and libicu66 were already installed, but I still get this error.