# Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system in Asp.Net Core 3 - ubuntu

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to run a Asp.Net Core 3 application in Ubuntu 19.10 thru terminal using `dotnet run` command but it does not seem to work. I get this error.

> ```
> Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system.
> Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want
> to run with no globalization support.   
>  at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)   
>  at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
>  at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()   
>  at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()   
>  at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()   
>  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()   
>  at System.StringComparer..cctor()   
>  at System.StringComparer.get_OrdinalIgnoreCase()   
>  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationProvider..ctor()   
>  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationSource.Build(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder)
>  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()   
>  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder..ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder)
>  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.GenericHostWebHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureWebHost(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder, System.Action'1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder>)   
>  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.GenericHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder, System.Action'1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder>)   
>  at WebApplication.Program.CreateHostBuilder(System.String[])   
>  at WebApplication.Program.Main(System.String[])
> ```

I installed the dotnet core sdk using the ubuntu store and after that I also installed Rider IDE.

The weird thing here is that when I run the app using Rider it runs fine, the only issue is using terminal dotnet core commands.

Does anybody know what might be the issue ?

The application is created using Rider. I don't think that this plays a role but just as a side fact.

I know there are also other ways to install dotnet core in ubuntu but since the sdk is available in the ubuntu story I thought it should work out of the box and of course its an easier choice.

Also tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132275/ci-cannot-build-net-project-fails-with-couldnt-find-a-valid-icu-package-ins) but does not seem to work for me. Still the same issue happens after running the commands.

Comment: Might help you by adding this: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2186#issuecomment-472629489

Answer (score 95):

The alternative solution as described in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/globalization) is to set environment variable before running your app

```
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to run with no globalization support, you need to get `"System.Globalization.Invariant": true` into your published output `AppName.runtimeconfig.json` file as shown in the example below:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.0",
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Globalization.Invariant": true
    }
  }
}
```

You can add it manually every time you deploy by adding or updating the `AppName.runtimeconfig.json` file. Better yet, add it once to a `runtimeconfig.template.json` file like this:

```
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Globalization.Invariant": true
  }
}
```

Make sure that `runtimeconfig.template.json` is included in build/publish.

Answer (score 13):

It seem the package `libicu63` will provide the ico support for dotnet on Linux, at least on Debian'ish distros.

Update:

And it seems it's "missing" when doing a small installing of Debian (i.e. deselect all applications/system-options in the installation program, except for SSH server)

Comment: Worked for me! Ran into this issue after flashing a new image to my Beaglebone.

Comment: `libicu66` seems to be have been installed already, and I still this. Ubuntu 20

Comment: Maybe you need a newer or older libicxx version? What dotnet core version are you installing?

Comment: libicu67 in Debian 11 (Bullseye)

Comment: Worked for me on arch. I was playing with a bunch a new dotnet tools when it occured on a new tool, then I started having it on the microsoft.web.librarymanager.cli tool, which I use daily. Not sure what happened

Comment: For OpenSUSE (and potentially other RPM-based distros) installing the `libicu-devel` package solved the issue for me when doing `dotnet run .`.

Comment: it's called `libicu70` in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 7):

The trick around it on Ubuntu 20.04 based on this thread https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2186#issuecomment-671105420

`$export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1`

Answer (score 5):

Yes. When installing Github action in Debian. It is also required.

As the response from MrCalvin,
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -qqq libicu63` resolve my issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run your app without access to culture-specific data and behavior, you can just add this MSBuild property to your `.csproj` file:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Had to set this to true to avoid below error during `docker run`.
            (It was set to false by default. "false" means access to cultural data)

            "Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system.
            Please install libicu (or icu-libs) using your package manager and try again.
            Alternatively you can set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true
            if you want to run with no globalization support."
        -->
        <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization).

Answer (score 2):

edit your .bashrc file by adding the following line, e.g.:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

add

`export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1`

Ctrl+o, Ctrl+x

restart terminal and run pwsh again

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while trying to run Umbraco version 9.2.0. Fiddling with `System.Globalization.Invariant` was not a good solution as it broke globalization in the backoffice. This issue has been solved in v9.4: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/pull/11961

I didn't want to upgrade my Umbraco version to solve this, so I just copied the change in that commit to my project.

Simply go into the `.csproj` file of your web project and change the ICU package reference lines to:

```
<!-- Force windows to use ICU. Otherwise Windows 10 2019H1+ will do it, but older windows 10 and most if not all winodws servers will run NLS -->
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="68.2.0.9" />

  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption
    Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('linux')) Or $(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('win')) Or ('$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == '' And !$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('osx')))"
    Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu"
    Value="68.2.0.9" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60439#issuecomment-1100867919) helped me override the default ICU version to the one that's installed on the machine running arch linux.

```
export CLR_ICU_VERSION_OVERRIDE=$(pacman -Q icu | awk '{split($0,a," ");print a[2]}' | awk '{split($0,a,"-");print a[1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the Windows [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu) to install SDK dependencies and Runtime, watch out for the corresponding version to each Linux distribution to avoid compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I was having an issue with currency symbol in docker container. I'm using MigraDoc pdf generation library.
The solution that worked for me was found [in this docker issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1483)

Add the following environment variables to your docker file just below your base image declaration (update accordingly)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base    
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
        LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this problem in only specific VS Code projects to run/debug `dotnet core 3.1.xxx,  you need to add following settings locally in you VS Code settings file.

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT": "1"
    }
}
```

For more information check: [how to run a pre-configured command when new terminal is created in vs code for only opened folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77942326/how-to-run-a-pre-configured-command-when-new-terminal-is-created-in-vs-code-for/77943443#77943443)