# Dotnet Sonar Scanner for ubuntu error "Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system"

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, .net-core, sonarqube

Hello i am working on to impliment the dotnet core project scanning using sonar qube on ubuntu, but when i run the following commands to start scanning procedure i get error listed below, please note that i alraedy checked other links and solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119904/process-terminated-couldnt-find-a-valid-icu-package-installed-on-the-system-in) and [this](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2020/08/16/system-globalization-invariant-error-with-c-under-ubuntu-20-04/) but they did not worked for me

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"project-key"
dotnet build
dotnet sonarscanner end
```

the project managed to build successfully but with following error at the end

> Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the
> system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to
> true if you want to run with no globalization support.    at
> System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)    at
> System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
> at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()    at
> System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
> at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()    at
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()    at
> System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage(System.Reflection.Assembly,
> System.Resources.UltimateResourceFallbackLocation ByRef)    at
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.CommonAssemblyInit()    at
> System.Resources.ResourceManager..ctor(System.String,
> System.Reflection.Assembly)    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Resources.get_ResourceManager()    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Resources.get_AssemblyDescription()    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+d__4.MoveNext()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+d__4,
> SonarScanner.MSBuild, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5b62af9de6d7244]](d__4 ByRef)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+<Execute>d__4, SonarScanner.MSBuild, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5b62af9de6d7244]](<Execute>d__4 ByRef)    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(System.String[], SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.ILogger)    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+<Execute>d__3.MoveNext()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+<Execute>d__3, SonarScanner.MSBuild, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5b62af9de6d7244]](<Execute>d__3 ByRef)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+d__3, SonarScanner.MSBuild, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5b62af9de6d7244]](d__3 ByRef)    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(System.String[])    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+d__2.MoveNext()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+d__2,
> SonarScanner.MSBuild, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5b62af9de6d7244]](d__2 ByRef)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program+d__2,
> SonarScanner.MSBuild, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5b62af9de6d7244]](d__2 ByRef)    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Main(System.String[])    at
> SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.(System.String[])

Comment: Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support

Comment: i tried but somehow dotnet not detects this flag i think

Comment: Did you read following.  Many different good answers : https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2186?force_isolation=true