# Unable to run self contained .net core 5.0 application

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, dotnet-publish

I have a .NET core 5.0 ASPNET Web API application. This application runs perfectly locally on Visual Studio.

Now I am trying to publish the self contained app using following command:

```
dotnet publish -c release testdb.sln --framework net5.0 --runtime linux-x64 /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false --nologo --self-contained true -v m
```

I am trying to run it over a Red Hat Linux image (image details below):

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

This is how my docker file looks like:

```
FROM testrepo.net/images/base/rhel:7.6

#published code is copied inside redhat folder
COPY redhat/  APP/
WORKDIR APP
RUN chmod +x /APP
RUN chmod +x testdb.dll
RUN chmod 777 /APP

ENTRYPOINT "./testdb.dll"
```

When I run this this image, I get error: .**/testdb.dll: cannot execute binary file**

I am not sure if this is due to invalid [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids) I specified during publish command or something else.

Comment: The error is correct - you can't just run a dll. What you need to do instead is run `dotnet testdb.dll`. this means your base docker image will need to have the dotnet cli installed (or you will need to install it as part of your dockerfile - most people use the MS provided images though: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/)

Comment: @RB. How do I fix it? This is a Linux image without aspnet runtime. So I cannot say ~ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","testdb.dll"]~ How can I fix this ?

Comment: Sorry - i was on mobile and accidentally clicked save. I've answered your question in my original comment now :) use an ASP.Net base image for an asp.net application of course - MS provide images for all occasions :)

Comment: @RB. Since this is a self contained image, shouldn't I can run the app without dotnet cli or dotnet runtime ?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I missed that detail. It should also have created a file called `testdb` (no extension) - that's the executable - you run that. Apologies for not reading the question properly!

Comment: See here for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230574/15393

Comment: changed `RUN chmod +x testdb.dll` to `RUN chmod +x testdb` and changed `ENTRYPOINT "./testdb.dll"` to `ENTRYPOINT "./testdb"` these changes helped. But Now I am getting another error : `Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.` I will investigate further. Thank you

Comment: @SharpCoder check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119904/process-terminated-couldnt-find-a-valid-icu-package-installed-on-the-system-in to fix issue with Globalization.

Comment: @akseli : I googled and found same fix and its working :) Thank you

Comment: @RB. Thank you !! Add your solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

changed RUN `chmod +x testdb.dll` to `RUN chmod +x testdb`
and changed `ENTRYPOINT "./testdb.dll"` to ENTRYPOINT "./testdb"

With these two changes I was able to fix the issue.